# Как сделать редирект с поддомена до момента проверки https

Tags: nginx, https, redirect

Как сделать обычный редирект понятия имеется, а вот проблема в том что при переходе в браузер не выводил сообщения "Подключение не защищено" а сразу делал редирект https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkDLZ.png , веб-сервер nginx, может кто-то стыкался?

Comment: Нужно или стирать https из ссылок, или ставить валидный сертификат на веб-сервере. Без этого браузер не позволит делать никакие редиректы, потому что будет подозревать, что редирект может быть подсунут злоумышленником

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как работает `https`:

1. Браузер отправляет запрос на создание шифрованного соединения, сервер отправляет ему свой сертификат.
2. Если сертификат невозможно проверить, то браузер предупреждает - доверять этому сайту не стоит. Дальше обмен данными не происходит на стороне браузера, пока вы либо не согласитесь принять сомнительный сертификат, либо не закроете страницу.
   `(вы здесь)`
3. В случае валидного сертификата, или вы согласились принять соединение даже не смотря на предупреждения, браузер и сервер создают шифрованное соединение.
4. Браузер передает параметры запроса к серверу по установленному шифрованному соединению, а сервер их обрабатывает и возвращает ответ, будь то страница или редирект на другую страницу/домен.

В вашем случае поможет только валидный сертификат или `http` соединение.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь мне понятно.